# Maven POM executes the old test case class from TestNG XML

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I have been using Selenium with JAVA along with Maven and TestNG on Eclipse. My tests are running fine. But whenever I change my JAVA class name in TestNG.xml file, the Maven POM still picks and executes the old class mentioned previously in TestNG.xml.

1. For Example my TestNG.xml has mentioned "Class1".
2. When I run "mvn test" command, "Class1" is executed.
3. Now I change class name in TestNG.xml to "Class2".
4. I run "mvn test" command, but still "Class1" is executed whereas "Class2" should have been executed. 
   I have tried updating the eclipse project and clean the mvn project but it still executes the old test class.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Step-1 : Manually Clean everything from /Target/ folder if its contains anything(Take Backup of class folder)

- Test classes
- Classes
- Surefire Reports
- Generated Sources
- Maven Status

Step-2 : Run Maven Build-Compile (Check if class file is generated)

Step-3 : Its done. Run your Test and Verify.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. What I have observed is that there is an "old" folder made inside "target/surefire reports" folder. This "old" folder contains "Testng.xml" which has combined both Class1 and Class2 in it, so it is running both test classes.

Comment: That is what I have informed above, Once you remove everything from target folder and then on your new build it will be new instance. And So It will work.

Answer (score 0):

mvn test will run test cases , it will not clean the code , so use below command

```
 mvn clean test
```

clean goal remove all files generated by the previous build

Answer (score 0):

As you are using *Maven* and *TestNG* through Eclipse, once you make changes in `testng.xml`:

- Ensure that `testng.xml` is placed in designated location and **not** within **target** directory or with any of it's subdirectories as the output of *Maven Test* is pushed to **target** directory.
- Before you execute your tests ensure that you have *saved* the modified `testng.xml`.
- Saving the `pom.xml` will also save the changes in `testng.xml`.
- Clean the **target** directory.
- Through CLI / IDE (Eclipse) to flush out previous dependencies:

  ```
  mvn clean
  ```
- Through CLI / IDE (Eclipse) to download and install the necessary dependencies:

  ```
  mvn install
  ```
- Through CLI / IDE (Eclipse) to execute test:

  ```
  mvn test
  ```
- Refresh the **target** directory and view the results.